# Creating multiple language versions from single latex source by fetching translation from file

Tags: macros, languages

I could not really find anything matching, maysome someone got an idea or a starting point:

I want to maintain a collection of documents written in Kile, Using LaTeX converted by xetex into pdf format. These documents have to be updated from time to time. I required each document to be available in two or three languages.

I do not want to maintain separate source files/collections for  the different languages, since this will certainly lead to documents running out of sync. Instead I imagine something like this:

```
- each token of natural language ("phrase") will be enclosed in a macro
- the macro fetches the translation of the phrase from a local service
- this service could be a script reading translations from a file
```

Since there are applications suitable to maintain such phrase collections this appears to be a natural approach to me. However, I fail to find a good starting point..

Comment: Found op4a myself: http://po4a.alioth.debian.org/, however this changes the document source which I think is the wrong way to go.

Comment: Some related (duplicate?) questions: [Is it possible to keep my translation together with original text](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5076/2693) and [Guide to managing multiple resume with one LaTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1647/2693).

Comment: One more related question: [Is it possible to use some sort of internationalization in LaTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/59866/12850)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, I managed to put together my own solution by trying around and considering examples I found elsewhere. 
This is what I currently use, near the start of my project. It works fine so far:

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% this is a document holding multiple languages
% switch between ENGLISH and GERMAN by commenting one of the following lines:
\usepackage[ngerman,english]{babel} % makes ENGLISH content
%\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel} % makes GERMAN content
% this is the macro to define phrases in two languages:
\newcommand{\babel}[2]{\ifnum\pdfstrcmp{\languagename}{english}=0 {#2}\else{#1}\fi}
\newcommand{\babelDE}[1]{\ifnum\pdfstrcmp{\languagename}{ngerman}=0 {#1}\fi}
\newcommand{\babelEN}[1]{\ifnum\pdfstrcmp{\languagename}{english}=0 {#1}\fi}
% example:   \babel{Deutscher Text}{english text}
% example:   \babelDE{deutscher Text}
% example:   \babelEN{english text}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
```

Answer (score 7):

Using the [iflang](https://ctan.org/pkg/iflang) package it is possible to write a slightly cleaner command equivalent to the one in the previous answer:

```
\usepackage[ngerman,english]{babel}
%\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage{iflang}

\newcommand{\babel}[2]{\IfLanguageName{english}{#1}{#2}}
```

Comment: Interesting, thanks. I will take a look into it, though I currently do not have any documents maintained in LaTeX. Guess that will get interesting again for my next application ;-)

Comment: @BrunoHass I am trying to understand how your code works and I am getting exactly the opposite choice of text for the macro ``\babel`` . For example, if I run your code above with the command ``\babel{Deutscher Text}{english text}`` I get the ``Deutscher Text`` while I believe the correct should be the ``english text``. Would you be able to extend your code just a few lines that make it complete?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and @KJO suggested the `catchfilebetweentags` package as described in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/4952/170109.
It worked for me.

Comment: Could you please add more context to your answer? Otherwise this is only a link-only answer and will be deleted.

Comment: I think there is no need of a context. I answered to @arkasha's question. I think anyone can go to the link. If not please delete my answer.

Comment: Then you can post that answer here.