# What if I use a \def name starting with "if"

Tags: macros

Following this [answer to *Is it possible to use some sort of internationalization in LaTeX?*](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/61583/8231) I'm setting up my own dictionaries.

When compiling the files I get this error:

```
! Use of \if doesn't match its definition.
```

and I guess is why I named a *term* as `if_foreign_buyer`

```
\def \if_foreign_buyer{You can only...}
```

removing starting `if` solves the problem

*Any solution, other than not starting terms with* `if`?

Moreover I would like to start all terms with a underscore `_` so I can grab them with a `sed` command and create dictionaries from terms in the master file.

*Also this seems not allowed. Really?*

Comment: You can't have `_` in a command name

Comment: you have to change the catcode of _ before you can use it as a letter.

Comment: @neurino You might want to take a look at [What do \makeatletter and \makeatother do?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8351). While that question is about `@`, the general idea of catcodes and 'letters' applies here too: nothing to do with `if` _per se_.

Comment: Also take a look at [What exactly do \csname and \endcsname do?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39380)

Comment: Ok, got it, I'll switch to camelCase then... Where do I read what is exactly allowed in a `\def` name?

Comment: @neurino You can grep your sequences by simply using a common prefix for them: `\newcommand{\NEifforeignbuyer}{...}`

Comment: @egreg: I know but it decreases readability...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The problem here is that non-letters like `_` are not allowed in macro names and not taken as part of the name. Any text after `\def\themacro` and the `{` of the macro replacement text is taken as the *parameter text* which must match the actual input. With your code you are (re-)defining the TeX primitive `\if` as a macro which awaits and removes `_foreign_buyer` after it and replaces it with `You can only...`. Then the first use of `\if` (inside a package or a LaTeX core macro) which isn't followed by `_foreign_buyer` throws a TeX error.

You shouldn't use `_` as part of macro names and if you do you need to ensure that they have the correct *catcode*, namely 11 "*letter*", while being defined and when used. 
This can be done using `` \catcode`\_=11\relax `` but is not recommended and will break code which relies on the default meaning of `_` as an subscript command in math-mode.

Having `if` in front of a macro name is not a problem and fully OK. The only restriction are `\ifxxx`s defined by `\newif` where it is assumed that they start with `if`. The first two letters are then always stripped to produce `\xxxtrue` and `\xxxfalse`. This doesn't affect macro definitions though.

Comment: Just remember that plenty of short command name starting with `\if` are "reserved": `\if`, `\ifx`, `\ifnum`, `\ifcat`, ...

Comment: I'd underline that this is not related to `\if`: also `\def\box_good{...}` will have catastrophic consequences.

Comment: What about a tip to how _naming_ `\def` names so I can grep them easily with a regexp? C `gettext` is always aliased as `_` that's why I wanted to start terms' name with a underscore...

Comment: Actually, the current LaTeX definition of `\newif` *doesn't* require that the following control sequence's name starts with `if`. You can get funny consequences from `\newif\xyz`, `\newif\xy` and `\newif\x` (in order of increasing fun). Also `\expandafter\newif\csname\endcsname` is quite interesting.

Comment: @egreg: Didn't I wrote this? "assumed to be if" ... "first two letters are always stripped" etc.

Comment: @MartinScharrer I just wanted to point that out explicitly; somebody could not be aware of it. Another subtle point is that `\newif` *doesn't* check whether the following conditional is already defined.

Answer (score 9):

There is almost nothing really bad if you use `_` in command names, provided you have

```
\catcode`\_=11
```

before starting the definition of those commands and never revert the choice.

You can even continue to use `_` in math formulas by adding

```
\mathcode`\_=\string"8000
\begingroup
\catcode`\_=\active
\global\let_\sb
\endgroup
```

However such a naming scheme is non standard and definitely not recommendable. With some `babel` languages it may even go wrong.

I don't see how

```
\command_with_underscore
```

will increase readability over

```
\NEcommand
```

that's as easily searchable.

An example, just to show how this can work.

```
\documentclass{article}

% Start of document commands
\catcode`\_=11
\mathcode`\_=\string"8000
\begingroup
\catcode`\_=\active
\global\let_\sb
\endgroup

\newcommand{\foreign_buyer}{whatever}

\begin{document}
Here we use \foreign_buyer, and also a formula $a_{1}$.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Starting a command name with `\if` is definitely bad practice, unless it is a *real* conditional, introduced with `\newif`.

---

Notice that without `` \catcode`\_=11 ``, when you say

```
\def\if_foreign_buyer{...}
```

you're actually (re)defining the very important primitive command `\if` and this will cause sure disasters with *any* document.

---

Note. The command `\sb` is defined by `\let\sb=_` in the LaTeX kernel, so its meaning doesn't change when one modifies the category code of the underscore character. So it's always available as a substitute for it.

In this application we are telling TeX that `_` in math mode should behave like a command, which expands to `\sb`, that is it will just do the right thing. However, macros that rely on the presence of `_` will be fooled by this, so some package or macro might fail (not commonly used, but I've seen some cases where a macro tests for a following `_`).

Comment: You don't see how `\command_with_underscore` will increase readability over `\NEcommand` probably because never followed [python's creator Guido Van Rossum' Style Guide for Descriptive Names](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#descriptive-naming-styles) ;) Anyway... LaTeX is all but readability and Python zen. Try this: `python -c "import this" | grep -i readability`

Comment: @neurino For us TeX people, `@` is the magic letter so `\command@with@extr@s` or similar would be 'normal' :-)

Comment: @neurino I don't find any guide there, just a list of common conventions. As long as you stick to a convention, there's no difference between them. Of course, different backgrounds can lead to different opinions about readability.

Comment: @egreg: no intention to be polemic — get it as a joke ;) — but if someone like python's dad names a document *Style Guide* I'd definitively get it as... a guide. :)) I agree about different backgrounds but having used both I can't say a LaTeX script is as readable as a python script, however I look at it. Moreover if you have to _tweak_ something to your needs. My humble opinion tho.

Comment: @neurino From that "Style guide": "The naming conventions of Python's library are a bit of a mess, so we'll never get this completely consistent". `;-)`

Answer (score 2):

Use the hyphen instead and it is easier:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\makeatletter
\@namedef{if-foreign-buyer}{You can only...}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\csname if-foreign-buyer\endcsname

\end{document}
```

Comment: Probably should avoid the `minimal` class: [Why not use the minimal class](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42114/why-not-use-the-minimal-class).

Comment: No! Not when using examples without any font settings.

Comment: Ok. I was just thinking that the more examples newbies see with `minimal` class will result in more people using it for a MWE as there is no indication in the answer as to the specific reason why you used the `minimal` class.

Comment: that is only one part of the story the other one is that it is much more easier to find problems whithout using a lot of unneeded code.

Comment: I don't get it: I need to change the definition '\def \termName{term translation}` to \@namedef{term-name}{term translation} and change the name it's invoked, right? Will it work with arguments too?

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\let\mydef\@namedef
\let\myuse\@nameuse
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\mydef{foreign_buyer}{jfbu}
\mydef{foreign_seller}{egreg}


The foreign seller \myuse{foreign_seller} is definitely infinitely more of a
\TeX pert than the foreign buyer \myuse{foreign_buyer}.


\end{document}
```

Comment: Maybe a word or two how `\@namedef` and `\@nameuse` work, and what the difference to `\let` are, would be helpful.

Comment: @mafp I used `\let` simply to avoid having all the time in the document to say `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`. As for how they work, they are just wrappers around the basic `\csname..\endcsname` construction which allows to build control sequences with non-letters (it turns out that in the case of the underscore, contrarily to `%`, `{` or `}` or an active character expanding to something else than ultimately some characters, it goes through without trouble within such a construction).

Comment: and if in the above you then at the end do ``\catcode`_=11`` you can check that `\foreign_buyer` acts as expected.

Comment: let me state more precisely that you _can_ use `{` and `}` inside `\csname...\endcsname`, however not when using the wrappers `\@namedef` and `\@nameuse`.

Comment: See Herbert answer: will it work with arguments too?